How to transform generalised (polar) coordinates into cartesian coordinates?
I have a set of observations $D=(q(t_i), p(t_i))$ for $i=1,...,n_{data}$, where $q(t_i), p(t_i) \in R^n$. It is known that the $(q(t_i), p(t_i))$ represent angles and angular  momenta of a mechanical system. Let's say that it's a double pendulum, where:
$$H = \frac{p_1^2 + 2 p_2^2 - 2 p_1 p_2 \cos(q_1 - q_2)}{2 (1 + \sin^2(q_1 - q_2))} - 2 \cos(q_1) - \cos(q_2),
$$
such that $D$ represent solutions of the Hamiltonian ODE with the above Hamiltonian. Here we have assumed all the parameters such as the lengths and masses are dimensionless and equal to one.
It is known that the mechanical system has a simpler expression for the Hamiltonian in cartesian coordinates $(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, p_{x_1}, p_{y_1}, p_{x_2}, p_{y_2)}$,  given by some polynomial $$H_{cartesian} = \mathbf{p_x}^T\mathbf{p_x}+\mathbf{p_y}^T\mathbf{p_y} + y_1 + y_2.$$
This is assumed to be true.
I'd like to know a transformation (or embedding) $$E: (q_1, q_2, p_1, p_2) \mapsto (x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, p_{x_1}, p_{x_2}, p_{y_1}, p_{y_2})$$ such that transformed data $E(D)$ represents the solution of the Hamiltonian ODE with $H_{cartesian}$. This ODE will have extra constrains that are implicit in the generalised coordinates. But I don't need to know that explicitly as that will also be implicit in the data, which is fine for my purposes.
I'd also like to have the inverse transformation $P$, a projection, such that $P(E(D))=D$.
My question is the following: if the generalised coordinates represent the angles angular momenta of a mechanical system (could be an n-pendulum), then is the transformation $E$ always given by the following
$$E: (q_1, q_2, p_1, p_2) \mapsto L(\cos(q_1), \sin(q_1), \cos(q_2), \sin(q_2), \cos(q_1)p_1, \sin(q_1)p_1, \cos(q_2)p_2, \sin(q_2)p_2)$$
for some invertible linear transformation $L$ (i.e., some matrix)?
I can find such an $L$ to fit the data in this case. But I'd like $H_{cartesian}(E(p,q))$ to be polynomial. Would this work?
For example, the position of the second mass in the double pendulum is the sum of the $y$-components of both masses: $y_2 = \sin(q_1)+\sin(q_2)$, which is a linear combination of the above coordinates.
